# When a simple product is removed from grouped product in admin panel in Mage 2.4.5. Here comes issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, database, magento2.4.5

In Magento 2.4.5 vanilla when creating a new grouped product, let's suppose this grouped product already has 20 simple products.
Step # 1:
Add the 21th product in grouped product table in product edit page

Step # 2:
Re-moved the product order from the 21th order to 2nd or 3rd order by drag and drop.

Step # 3:
And finaly when remove that product from the list in grouped product, the sorting get worse of this table.

Here is the screenshot of disturbed sort order in this table:
[image]

I think calling the sorting function after deleting the product from this grouped product list may fix this issue. But still confused about how to sort the order after deleting the product from grouped product. Looking for an opinion or code that fixes this issue in magento 2.4.5 default.

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the sorting? I cannot tell from the image. How would you expect it to be?

Comment: The issue is that the products are not sorted by their ids. like ascending or descending order.